# c# file handling problem

Tags: c#

In my c# window application. I have 2 folders in the same path where exe is exist. One is Input folder where we put all files for process and second is processed folder where after processing files are moved.

Let say we have file name 1.txt at input folder after processing the file is cut from input and moved into processed folder. Immediatly when i placed same name file 1.txt at input folder then after processing it will again moved into processed folder where already another file exist of same name 1.txt.

Her i found that old 1.txt automatically moved out from processed folder and comes in the path where exe is placed. and new 1.txt will comes in processed folder.

I would like to know whether dotnet behaves in same way or i did something wrong?

Comment: It is a Programatical error, please check your code when you are saving/moving the file. Are you using - System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/FolderName/" ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not part of .NET (or the underlying Win32) to move files when they are overwritten. So, yes it is something you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to explicitly specify the path.

Also beware of using `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory`, because that is the systemwide current directory.  Another program (like Windows Explorer, or some other program's file open/save dialog) can change that.

If it's a WinForms app you can use `Application.StartupPath`.  If not I think you can use
`System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Location)`

Answer (score -1):

**View > Solution Explorer > Right Click on 1.txt > Properties > Copy to output directory**

NOTE:*Your problem has got nothing to do with .NET.*